# How to use java.util.Arrays

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the java.util.Arrays class in JavaSE 6 but not sure how i would implement it? on an array that I have generated?

before the start of the class i have

```
import java.util.Arrays
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to ask is how to use Arrays in java.  In which case you don't import java.util.Arrays, you use the array syntax.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Java Arrays

To declare an array of integers, you start with:

```
int[] myArray;
```

To instantiate an array of ten integers, you can try:

```
myArray = new int[10];
```

To set values in that array, try:

```
myArray[0] = 1; // arrays indices are 0 based in Java
```

Or at instantiation:

```
int[] myArray2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

To get values from the array, try:

```
System.out.println(myArray[0]);
```

To print all the values in an array, try:

```
// go from 0 to one less than the array length, based on 0 indexing
for(int i = 0; i < myArray2.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray2[i]);
}
```

For more information, the [tutorial from Sun/Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) will be of great help.  You can also check out the [Java language specification on Arrays](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html).

#### Using the Arrays Utility Class

[java.util.Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) contains a bunch of [static methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).  Static methods belong to the class and do not require an instance of the class in order to be called.  Instead they are called with the class name as a prefix.

So you can do things like the following:

```
// print a string representation of an array
int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

Or

```
// sort a list
int[] unsorted = {3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6};
Arrays.sort(unsorted);
```

Comment: "In Java an array is not an object (a descendant of java.util.Object). Instead, it is a primitive type."

Really?  Since when is an array not an object?

Answer (score 8):

Well let's say you have an array

```
int[] myArray = new int[] { 3, 4, 6, 8, 2, 1, 9};
```

And you want to sort it. You do this:

```
// assumes you imported at the top
Arrays.sort(myArray);
```

Here's the whole shebang:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = new int[] { 3, 4, 6, 8, 2, 1, 9};
        Arrays.sort(myArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
    }
}
```

And that results in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>java ArrayTest
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]

C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided enough information about what you are trying to do.  `java.util.Arrays` only exposes static methods, so you simply pass in your array and whatever other params are necessary for the particular method you are calling.  For instance `Arrays.fill(myarray,true)` would fill a boolean array with the value `true`.

Here is the javadoc for [java.util.Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static import

```
import static java.util.Arrays.*;

int[] ints = {3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6};
sort(ints);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

double array[] = {1.1,2.3,5.6,7.5, 12.2, 44.7,4.25, 2.12};
Arrays.sort(array,1,3); 
for(int i =0;i <array.length;i++){

System.out.println(array[i]);
}
}
```

result:

"1.1,2.3,5.6,7.5,12.2,44.7,4.25,2.12"